# How to load Docker environment variables in container

Tags: docker, environment-variables, systemd

I'm building an image that is based on an ubuntu image with systemd. I need to start 
TigerVNC as a service which depends on some environment variables that I have defined in my 
Dockerfile, like the password.

```
FROM ubuntu-systemd

ENV VNC_PW="some-password"

ENTRYPOINT ["/lib/systemd/systemd"]
```

The unit file for this service has a line that is:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l root -c "/some/script.sh"
```

Since systemd has its own environment, I don't have access to the environment variables
defined in my Dockerfile. I was expecting that running the script as root with
a login shell (the '-l' flag) would give me access to these variables but it does not.
I know the variables I need are in **/proc/1/environ** but I don't know how to load them, for 
example adding something in the **.profile** file for root.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you set the environment directly in the unit file or in an override drop-in (in `/etc/systemd/system/<yourservice>.service.d/overridefile.conf`) ? In section `Service` => `Environment="VNC_PW=somepassword"`

Comment: Because I would like to override the password when running the console: ```docker container run ... -e VNC_PW="another_password"```. Thanks a lot, for your hit anyway.

Comment: Well then just don't use systemd which is kind of awkward anyway in a docker container. Unless you have a very particular reason to do so, each container should contain a single service that you launch with its command. Now your command becomes `/some/script.sh` and it will read your env vars without problems.

Comment: Thanks again @Zeitounator. This container is for testing and I need the gnome desktop running and, although I have tried for weeks, I'm not been able of doing so without systemd. I've heard of a systemd replacement [https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement] but I'd prefer to keep on using systemd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit tricky but I can load the environment variables in the /some/script.sh in the ExecStart property by including the following line:

```
export `xargs --null --max-args=1 echo < /proc/1/environ`
```