# Environment Variables inside the container, but not used in the bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I have an application that runs inside a docker container. First I build the image and then run the container. My run command is:

```
docker run --rm -it -e MODE=custom -e Station=RT -e StartDateReport=2022-09-10 -e Period=1 my-image:1.0.0
```

I declare the variables `MODE, Station, StartDateReport and Period` as environment variables. When I start a terminal from the container and type `echo $MODE` I will get the correct value, `custom`.

So far, so good, but I am interested in using these variables in a `bash script`. For example in `start.sh` I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $MODE == custom ]]; then
   // do sth
fi
```

and here inside the script my variable `MODE` is `undefined`, and hence I obtain wrong results.

**EDIT**

As discussed in the comments below, my application if based on a cronjob to start running.

**I managed to solve by myself the problem and the answer is in the comments.**

Comment: There is nothing special in docker to change behavior of bash. Have you tried with quotes: `"$MODE" == "custom"` or with `-eq` operator?

Comment: How do you start `start.sh`? Do you start it in docker?

Comment: I use a cronjob. * * * * * cd /app/ && bash start.sh >> /var/log/cron.log &. I believe here is the problem, @KamilCuk. I apparently don't declare the variables for the execution of the script.

Comment: I do not understand. So how is docker related to a cronjob? How are your docker tests related to the cronjob?

Comment: I want to run my application at specific periods of time. start.sh is the starting point and the first thing that should run. * * * * * cd /app/ && bash start.sh >> /var/log/cron.log & just starts start.sh, in this case, every minute.

Comment: See this if it helps: https://github.com/diegoferigo/devenv/issues/2

Comment: If a cron daemon is involved, you should make that clear in your question.  I believe it's normal for cron to reset the environment of the processes it launches.

Comment: ```bash start.sh``` starts a new bash subshell without the env variables or they are lost in subshell. Have you tried ```chmod +x ./start.sh && ./start.sh```? I believe you need an `export foo=bar` statement in your `~./.bashrc`

Comment: What you describe generally works, so the problem must be in something you don't describe. Please extract a [mcve] and then [edit] your question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem, so I will post the answer here to help others that have the same problem. I found the solution here: [How to load Docker environment variables in container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154178/how-to-load-docker-environment-variables-in-container)

I included `export xargs --null --max-args=1 echo < /proc/1/environ` in `start.sh`

Thus, `start.sh` will be:

```
#!/bin/bash

export xargs --null --max-args=1 echo < /proc/1/environ

if [[ $MODE == custom ]]; then
   // do sth
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In your environment, does your variable definition have the form

```
export MODE="custom"
```

Modified version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

test -z "${MODE}" && ( echo -e "\n\t  MODE was not exported from calling environment.\n" ; exit 1 )

if [[ $MODE == custom ]]
then
    #// do sth
    echo "do sth"
fi
```